# UIScrollView setZoomscale does not work from ViewWillApper

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Hey guys I googled around a bit, and read some Topics here on stack overflow but no one cloud help me really , so i hope you can help me.
I have an UIWebView which display an local saved PDF which is working very fine, but i also want to set the zoom level when the PDF is loaded. I solved it this way.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    WebView.scalesPageToFit = true
    if(defaults.objectForKey("positionY") != nil){
        WebView.scrollView.setZoomScale(defaults.objectForKey("zoomlevel") as! CGFloat, animated: false)
        let offest = CGPoint(x: defaults.objectForKey("positionX") as! CGFloat, y: defaults.objectForKey("positionY") as! CGFloat)
        WebView.scrollView.setContentOffset(offest, animated: false)

        print(defaults.objectForKey("zoomlevel") as! CGFloat)
    }
```

But this is not really nice because, it looks bad to the user, so i tried to move my Code to ViewWillAppear, but then it does not work any more, and the pdf is not zoomed.
Thanks for any solution ideas :)

Edit as i wrote i a comment below i printed the value of the Zoomscale after seting it.

```
        WebView.scrollView.setContentOffset(offest, animated:false)
        println(defaults.objectForKey("zoomlevel") as! CGFloat)
        println(WebView.scrollView.zoomScale)
```

If i do this in ViewWillAppear or ViewDidLoad, the first value ist the saved value like 1.82366, the second value is still 1.0. If i call this in ViewDidAppear the first and second value are equal except of the First appearance of the View (app start). So if it start the App it is the Same like described above for ViewWillAppear but if i come back from another ViewController via segue it works for ViewDidAppear.

Comment: Where do you initialize you defaults object ?

Comment: Direct in the variable declaration `class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    var defaults  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` It is ok ? Sry if this is a noob question but i'm quite new to iOS Development. But if i move it to ViewWillAppear it returns the right value for the print call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question is probably too old now, but I finally solved it in my swift code, I will put it here it may be useful for others:
for `webview.scrollview.setzoomscale` to work, the `zoomscale` should be between `maximumzoomscale` and `minimumzoomscale` properties. both of these are 1 by default that's why the zooming does not work for you.Add this and it should be fine:

```
webView.scrollview.maximumZoomScale = CGFloat(10) // or any number higher than your zoomscale
```

and this should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Setting content offset before view is laid out has no effect at all. To fix it you must call `layoutIfNeed()` method to immediately lay out the specific view

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    WebView.layoutIfNeeded()
    WebView.scalesPageToFit = true
    if(defaults.objectForKey("positionY") != nil){
        WebView.scrollView.setZoomScale(defaults.objectForKey("zoomlevel") as! CGFloat, animated: false)
        let offest = CGPoint(x: defaults.objectForKey("positionX") as! CGFloat, y: defaults.objectForKey("positionY") as! CGFloat)
        WebView.scrollView.setContentOffset(offest, animated: false)

        print(defaults.objectForKey("zoomlevel") as! CGFloat)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried it, it does not Work. When i change to another View and back the print printing a zoomlevel which is greater then one, but it does not looked zoomed. I also figured out that the zoomScale is not changed the return of this code is e.g. `WebView.scrollView.setContentOffset(offest, animated:false)
            println(defaults.objectForKey("zoomlevel") as! CGFloat)
           println(WebView.scrollView.zoomScale)` Is for the saved CGFloat 1.4531 and the return of the scrollView is 1.0